# Read a file line that changes but the structure of the line is known

Tags: c, file, int, line

I have a file that is organized line by line and the structure of all lines was defined by me but the contents of each line can increase or decrease according to two variables that the same line contains.

**Line Example:** 1 Andre 2 0 5 13 05 2011 4 13 05 2011

'1' represents the user ID

'Andre' represents the name associated to the ID

'2 0' subdivides: '2' represents how many movies the user as taken home AND '0' represents how many movies reservations the user has.

So far the line is following the pattern %d %s %d %d and they can be stored in the variables I want.

Now the hard part comes. Depending on the '2 0' part, the program knows that has to read the pattern %d %d %d %d ('5 13 05 2011' and '4 13 05 2011' - represent dates of movies taken home) 2 times and also the program knows that after reading 2 times the previous pattern it knows that i doesn't need to read anything else due to the zero part in '2 0'.

**Example of line with more data:** 1 Andre 2 1 5 13 05 2011 4 13 05 2011 7 14 05 2011

'2 1'

The '2' part tells the program that in that line it should read '5 13 05 2011' and '4 13 05 2011' to variable_one[i][4] (example)

The '1' part tells the program that in that line it should read '7 14 05 2011' to variable_two[i][4] (example)

I'm using `fscanf(file, "%d %s %d %d", &id[i],&nomes[i],&livros_num[i][0],&livros_num[i][1]);` to read '1 Andre 2 0' but how can i read the rest of the line according to '2 0'?

Comment: I don't understand your date format. Month Day `?` Year ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your first call of fscanf, you need to loop depending on the variables you read. You seem to have already realized that the `int`'s you read in your first call determine the number of extra reads you need in the line.

```
int i;
for ( i=0; i< livros_num[i][0]; i++ ) {
    int something, day, month, year; // 'something' is unclear to me in your code
    fscanf( file, "%d %d %d %d", &something, &day, &month, &year );
    // store these variables wherever
}

// same procedure for second number
for ( i=0; i< livros_num[i][1]; i++ ) {
    int something, day, month, year; // 'something' is unclear to me in your code
    fscanf( file, "%d %d %d %d", &something, &day, &month, &year );
    // store these variables wherever
}
fscanf( file, "%s\n" ); // I'm NOT sure if this is nessecary, to move the file to the next line
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/).
Here's an example:

```
int int1;
char char_buf[BUF_SIZE];
fscanf ( file_stream, "%d%s", &int1, char_buf);
```

Comment: i already have fscanf to read the 4 objects (%d %s %d %d) because they're always 4 of them.

fscanf(file, "%d %s %d %d", &id[i],&nomes[i],&livros_num[i][0],&livros_num[i][1]);

Comment: but the problem comes when i need to read x values according to '2 0'

Comment: @andrepcg: I sorry..i read the question too fast. If you don't know the field number, probably it's better read the whole line as a string with fscanf, then tokenize it with strtok, and the reuse fscanf to extract the proper type from each token.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),f)

p = strtok (buf," ");
p1 = strtok (0," ");
p2 = strtok (0," "); 

p3 = strtok (0," "); 

n1 = atoi(p1);
n2=  atoi(p2);

i=0;
while(n1--)
{
  sscanf(p3,"%d %d %d %d", &v1[i],&v2[i],&v3[i],&v4[i] );
  strok(0," ");
  strok(0," ");
  strok(0," ");
  p3 =   strok(0," ");
  i++;

}

i=0;
while(n2--)
{
  sscanf(p3,"%d %d %d %d", &v2[i],&v2[i],&v2[i],&v2[i] );
  strok(0," ");
  strok(0," ");
  strok(0," ");
  p3 =   strok(0," ");
  i++;

}
```

Comment: @thelaws has more elegant solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008927/read-a-file-line-that-changes-but-the-structure-of-the-line-is-known/6009282#6009282

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
int j;
fscanf(file, "%d %s %d %d", &id[i],&nomes[i],&livros_num[i][0],&livros_num[i][1]);
for (j=0;j<livros_num[i][0];++j)
{
    fscanf(file,"%d %d %d %d",&variable_one[0],&variable_one[1],&variable_one[2],&variable_one[3]);
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you read the '2 0' you get two pieces of information: the number times you need to loop for the dates of the movies taken home and the number of times you need to loop to read all the reservations.

```
int i;
int num_movies_taken, num_movies_reserved;

// read all the dates of the movies taken home
num_movies_taken = livros_num[i][0];
for (i = 0; i < num_movies_taken; i++)
{
    fscanf("%d %d %d %d", ...);
}

// read all the reservations
num_movies_reserved = livros_num[i][1];
for (i = 0; i < num_movies_reserved; i++)
{
    fscanf("%d %d %d %d", ...);
}
```